# Why does java redirect fail?

Tags: python, shell

I've checked similar java redirect issues here but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to run a python 3.6 script in ubuntu 18.04 that calls a java program through a bash script.

The original coder confirms that the problem is with the paths contained in "tokenize_sent.sh" 
but several redirect tests have produced the same error below.

tokenize_sent.sh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor ../tmp/in.txt > ../tmp/out.txt
```

Bash script located here:

```
Datasets/stanford-parser-full-2017-06-09/tokenize_sent.sh
```

The good news is that the python script/bash is writing the correct text file to ../tmp/in.txt in the project directory.

The python script is run from project directory which contains all the necessary folders and their sub-folders including
required models and the stanford parser etc.

Datasets

InferSent

tmp  (correct in.txt written here but out.txt fails)

SentenceChange_Read2Files_MASTER.py

I'm new to python and java. Hoping it's a quick fix to tokenize_sent.sh.

Any help is appreciated.

---

python snippet with line 68 that calls "tokenize_sent.sh":

```
NEWLINE = '<NEWLINE>'
def tokenize_sentences(text):
    open('tmp/in.txt', 'w').write(text.replace('\n\n', NEWLINE))
    os.system('Datasets/stanford-parser-full-2017-06-09/tokenize_sent.sh')
    tokens = open('tmp/out.txt').read().split('\n')
    print('Total tokens in dataset', len(tokens))

    return [token for token in tokens if len(token) > 0]
```

---

Error when running "SentenceChange_Read2Files_MASTER.py"

```
Datasets/stanford-parser-full-2017-06-09/tokenize_sent.sh: line 7: ../tmp/out.txt: No such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SentenceChange_Read2Files_MASTER.py", line 162, in <module>
    changed = change_book(open(prefix + 'Jane Austen___Northanger 
Abbey.txt').read(), open(prefix + 'Bram Stoker___Dracula.txt').read())
File "SentenceChange_Read2Files_MASTER.py", line 90, in change_book
    toChangeSent = tokenize_sentences(toChange)
  File "SentenceChange_Read2Files_MASTER.py", line 68, in tokenize_sentences
    tokens = open('tmp/out.txt').read().split('\n')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tmp/out.txt'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please do not tag languages that have nothing to do with your question.  As your question has nothing to do with [tag:java], I have removed this tag for you.

Comment: Note that when you run `foo > bar`, the redirection to `bar` happens **before** the program `foo` is run (while the shell is still setting up the program's process environment, which includes directing its inputs and outputs). Thus, the language `foo` is written in cannot possibly change whether the redirection succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tmp/out.txt'

means that there is no file `tmp/out.txt` *relative to the directory where you ran the script from.* So when you run `Datasets/stanford-parser-full-2017-06-09/tokenize_sent.sh` it does **not** look for the file inside `./Datasets/stanford-parser-full-2017-06-09` but rather in `.`.

The solution is to either `cd` into the directory which all the paths are relative to or (much better) creating a solution which does not rely on relative paths (or where the relative path is explicitly passed to each script), but this is outside the scope of this answer.